# VirtualBox, как исправить ошибку ? error: cannot allocate kernel buffer | error: you need to load the kernel first

Tags: virtualbox

Создано виртуальная машина Linux Mint 21.
Установка через iso-образ (DVD)

Запускается и выводит ошибку:

error: cannot allocate kernel buffer
error: you need to load the kernel first

Подскажите пожалуйста источник для исправления этой ошибки если кто то сталкивался, прочту...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://whitefumes.wordpress.com/2021/06/08/ubuntu-18-04-desktop-error-cannot-allocate-kernel-buffer-error-you-need-to-load-the-kernel-first/

Comment: Огромное спасибо!